# How to fetch data from DB tables to json format? LARAVEL 5.8

Tags: json, laravel, database, controller, fetch

I'm an amateur front-end developer working on a web development project for my university. I'm going solo on this project have already finished the front-end part of the website. I used a temporary API to fetch the data that are passed on my views. Now, as I have to use a database, I build the database and I'm trying to fetch the data to my controllers. It is too complex for me, made almost zero progress so far. Making baby steps I'm now trying to fetch into a variable on my controller, JSON data containing all the table keys and values of a specific row. The response contains protected data and I have no idea how to fetch them the right way.

Any tip or advice would be much appreciated.

**My test server's controller**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use App\circuits;
use App\constructor_results;
use App\constructors;
use App\driver_standings;
use App\drivers;
use App\lap_times;
use App\pit_stops;
use App\qualifying;
use App\races;
use App\results;
use App\seasons;
use App\status;


use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

class HomeController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }

    /**
     * Show the application dashboard.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Support\Renderable
     */
    public function index()
    {

        $data = DB::table('circuits')
        ->select('circuits.*')
        ->where(['circuitId' => '6'])
        ->get();

        print_r(response()->json($data));       

    }
 
}
```

**The response**  *(The wanted values are shown in the end of line)*

```
Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse Object ( [data:protected] => [{"circuitId":"6","circuitRef":"monaco","name":"Circuit de Monaco","location":"Monte-Carlo","country":"Monaco","lat":"43.7347","lng":"7.42056","alt":"7","url":"http:\/\/en.wikipedia.org\/wiki\/Circuit_de_Monaco"}] [callback:protected] => [encodingOptions:protected] => 0 [headers] => Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\ResponseHeaderBag Object ( [computedCacheControl:protected] => Array ( [no-cache] => 1 [private] => 1 ) [cookies:protected] => Array ( ) [headerNames:protected] => Array ( [cache-control] => Cache-Control [date] => Date [content-type] => Content-Type ) [headers:protected] => Array ( [cache-control] => Array ( [0] => no-cache, private ) [date] => Array ( [0] => Tue, 09 Nov 2021 18:09:00 GMT ) [content-type] => Array ( [0] => application/json ) ) [cacheControl:protected] => Array ( ) ) [content:protected] => [{"circuitId":"6","circuitRef":"monaco","name":"Circuit de Monaco","location":"Monte-Carlo","country":"Monaco","lat":"43.7347","lng":"7.42056","alt":"7","url":"http:\/\/en.wikipedia.org\/wiki\/Circuit_de_Monaco"}] [version:protected] => 1.0 [statusCode:protected] => 200 [statusText:protected] => OK [charset:protected] => [original] => Illuminate\Support\Collection Object ( [items:protected] => Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [circuitId] => 6 [circuitRef] => monaco [name] => Circuit de Monaco [location] => Monte-Carlo [country] => Monaco [lat] => 43.7347 [lng] => 7.42056 [alt] => 7 [url] => http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circuit_de_Monaco ) ) ) [exception] => )
```

Comment: First of consider updating to Laravel 6 (LTS) or 8 as 5.* is no longer supported https://laravelversions.com/en

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-resources

(it should be valid for 5.8 as well https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-resources, the idea is the same)

> Of course, you may always convert Eloquent models or collections to
> JSON using their toJson methods; however, Eloquent resources provide
> more granular and robust control over the JSON serialization of your
> models and their relationships.

So you can add a new Circuit Eloquent model, describe all fields and etc there, and add the toJson method, which will return array (there you can map what you want to return from the model).

I prefer to go with API Resources because in the feature you might need different responses in different places.

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Resources;

use Illuminate\Http\Resources\Json\JsonResource;

class CircuitResource extends JsonResource
{
    /**
     * Transform the resource into an array.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return array
     */
    public function toArray($request)
    {
        //add all fields which you want to return from the Circuit model
        return [
            'id' => $this->id,
            'created_at' => $this->created_at,
            'updated_at' => $this->updated_at,
        ];
    }
}
```

Then in the controller, you will use it like

```
use App\Http\Resources\CircuitResource;
use App\Models\Circuit;

...

return response()->json(new CircuitResource(Circuit::find(6)));
```

Model will be

```
<?php
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Circuit extends Model
{
    /**
     * The primary key associated with the table.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $primaryKey = 'circuitId';
}
```

To find 1 item it is better to use `find()` method. But if you search more than one, you will receive a Collection object. In that case, you will need to use the appropriate method on the created resource class, and from action, you should return

```
return response()->json(new CircuitResource::collection(Circuit::all()));
```

Comment: replying to "Oleksandr H."
I created the resource. I passed the right fields in the resource and then run with the line:
"return response()->json(new CircuitResource(Circuit::find(6)));"

I get an error:
"SQLSTATE[HY000]"

Apparently it searching for a column circuit.id by default and it doesn't exist

Comment: @GkChris99 to fix it you need to tell in Circuit Eloquent class the name of your primary key(by default it is `id`), see https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#primary-keys)

Comment: @GkChris99 I've updated my answer, hope it is more clear how to use it.